# scss : Buttons to display fixed side by side

Tags: css, sass

Recently , i added a button to my mobile app. However , the buttons are displaying differently on mobile screen size.

For an example, when i run it on iphone 6+, the buttons display side by side as show below, But when i am displaying it on iphone 4, the second button is displaying below it rather than beside it.

I used percentage to make it responsive but apparently , something looks wrong with my sass.

for an example , i want the outlook to be as shown in the image regardless of what the screen size is .

[image]

this is my sass code

```
.IonFooter {
        button {
            width: 48%;
            height: 60px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 1.3em;
        }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: This should work just fine. The problem may lie with the borders and padding set, could you check and post those? It can be found easily in computed styles section in chrome inspector.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of your buttons is probably caused by the infamous `display: inline-block;` right margin "bug" (Check this [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) about the issue). It could also be caused by padding in the parent element.

Anyway, I suggest that you use flex to avoid having your buttons fall on multiple rows.

```
.IonFooter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    button {
        flex: 0 0 48%; // Grow: no, shrink: no, width: 48 %
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi sebastian , 

I tried using using your method , but the same problem is still persisting . I am using ionic framework. the problem is that, it has other classes elements  auto generated by the framework.